# incremental training SGD Classifier of Sklearn with sentences

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

How to incrementally train SGDClassifier available in Sklearn linear models for sentences.
It is usually trains with docs.But i want to train it with sentences one by one.I want to incrementally train it for tweets for sentiment analysis.Any explanation with example in python will be great help.

Task: Sentiment Analysis of Tweets
Doubt: Incrementally  training on labelled Tweets

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SGDClassifier has no notion of a document, only of a sample (feature vector). If you split your text into sentences, then vectorize those with `HashingVectorizer`, it should work just fine.

Comment: ya I did that today and it is working.actually yesterday I was not able to do that .was following the out of core implementation example in scikit-learn and was confused with minibatches.Thanks for the reply by the way... :)

Comment: @larsmans how we can write our own features .In hashing vectors how features are extracted??

Comment: @larsmans and how to fine tune the hashingvectorizer parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make list of sentences 
for example

```
sents=["I am x","I am Y"]
```

then transform it using HashingVectorizer and then use partial_fit to train it incrementally.
This worked for me.

Thanks